# Why ts_plot in package TSstudio show blank plot in RStudios but fine in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I want to try ts_plot from package TSstudio to plot a time series data, but it gave me this blank result.

```
install.packages("TSstudio")
library("TSstudio")
data(USgas)

# Ploting time series object
ts_plot(USgas, 
        title = "US Monthly Natural Gas Consumption",
        Ytitle = "Billion Cubic Feet")
```

[image]

However, when I redo the whole thing in Jupyter Notebook using R. It gave me a perfect result.

[image]

Could someone please give me some clue the reason why this happens and possible solutions?

Comment: can you add a MWE

Comment: Just edited the question. Thx for reminding me.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem [here is a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8uBGh7e.png)  also even though it doesn't show up in `Rstudio` it will show up in the rendered document